# Typehint function *args -> tuple[*args] with constraint on the args

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pylance

We want to type hint a function

```py
def f(*args:float)->tuple[float,...]:
   ...
   return tuple(args)
```

such that it is specified that the number of elements in the tuple matches the number of args.
Of course, the return here is a placeholder for more complicated logic.

We would like to use mypy or pylance to check if we always return a) the correct number of elements and b) the correct tyoe of all elements.

Using `TypeVarTuple` (https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#args-as-a-type-variable-tuple) would allow to specify that we return the same number of elements, but not the type.

Is there in current python (3.12) way to do it besides writing many overloads for 1-parameter, 2-parameter, 3-parameters etc?

Comment: I don't think there's any support for typing tuples to be a specific length not to mention you want to go one step further and take that length from the arguments passed to the function.

Comment: I think even with `TypeVarTuple`, it only lets you break the type of `*args` down into a combination of fixed-length, heterogeneous tuples and variable-length homogenous tuples, without capturing the *total* length of the arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Does [`def f[*Ts](*args: *Ts) -> tuple[*Ts]: ...`](https://pyright-play.net/?code=LAKFBMFMDMAJoNoCoAqBnAugCiQQwE4DmaAXLKmgJSwC0AfLAC4CuADgDaTLoYmiwCAdMNChcAGlgAjSQGNJ4WAF54WAOTQA9prWSAjJIBMggCyVQ%2BSADdIudgH1GAT1aQsuarADEsNI3wW1rYOzq5YUp4%2BAJYAdoyBNnaOLm6ykfDsmrjxIEA) work for you?

Comment: @InSync That wouldn't force the arguments to be `float`s, though.

Comment: @InSync this would work if I could bind the Ts to floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write a no-op decorator to make the signature of `f` reject attempts at passing a type that you don't want. The following example makes `f` reject any attempts at passing values which aren't compatible with `float`.

Demo: [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=d7f6fd4dcbab1e02140c1391e767eeca), [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYA7A5gfQKYA8baoDOwExcAhkQgLABQ9wAZggHQAqAmgAoCimAYQASvAQGkAkgDkA4gC56cJXFCRYcAMYQANtuwaYpYqwoAjDZWobc9RcoBicALxt2ybADUKUABQAiez8AGjhTCABXVAATJ2tWAQpdMz0AbVZ0kJhWAEFURABdAEo7JQAlZ1d3L18-UuDNCAA3b2AKVBgndihw7GK6ZTh2ahcstzBPb3ZwsD1-Ib8%2BuBLNbSpqTHttCAoYAHlUbUQEpNNZrO4oCBgILW0U0qKFfoHlKOwWTEwNRO1PnyJsNomCEAPQhABU3nQRDkcCYWx2hTgAFoAHxwUqw9KsWx0N4sKibbZ7A5HH7JbA%2BJiw%2BygpFouCOAA%2BcA2CJJh2Oq1O2CeAz8AoAIvpoDtsJQ4ZEDEYEBA4CAKABrcXAeBkQ6UDQabBgeDNKCtKLACyQEiGMiJOHsyhQdDhECEGBEAV%2BZZQbAwcJQVBw3EAAUJ7P2nPJPPo%2BLhPkhtphcHBQ3p6M9M2wKXjRHyfOU7s93pt0NxFBCpgqTB8AEZWAAGEIAJmrSLgAGI4LsxPQNCEoqX-ABmav1AAsDaULd4UEuUFhElQWnAO2APIQ7jgfiIMCg9Tw4wM2G7fnhxNddGwIXQIQAFj2AKzVkIANhHzbg48nsKk2D38ug4ua2h61DXHAkRgBQGiKvQQA)

```py
import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx

    F = t.TypeVar("F", bound=cx.Callable[..., t.Any])
    Ts = t.TypeVarTuple("Ts")
 
    class _FloatOnlyCallable(t.Protocol):
        def __call__(self, /, *args: float) -> t.Any: ...

def asFloatOnlyCallable(f: F, /) -> F | _FloatOnlyCallable:
    """Decorate a function to make it only accept variadic positional float arguments"""
    return f

@asFloatOnlyCallable
def f(*args: *Ts) -> tuple[*Ts]:
    return args
```

```
>>> a, b = f(1.0, 2.0)  # OK
>>> c, d = f("3.0", 4.0)  # Error: Incompatible type "str", expected "float"
>>> e, g, h = f(5.0, 6.0)  # Error: Need more values to unpack
```