# How do I check that parameters of a variadic callable are all of a certain subclass?

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy, pyright

This might be a tough one.

Suppose I have a type

```py
JSON = Union[Mapping[str, "JSON"], Sequence["JSON"], str, int, float, bool, None]
```

And I have a function

```py
def memoize[**P, T: JSON](fn: Callable[P,T]) -> Callable[P,T]:
    # ...make the function memoizable
    return wrapped_fn
```

How do I constrain the parameters of fn to all be subtypes of JSON? Alternatively, if this can't be done statically, how do I check this inside memoize before creating the wrapper?

I tried giving bounds to the ParamSpec variable **P, but it seems this isn't implemented yet. I also tried issubclass but this doesn't play nice with typehints.

Comment: Do you mean, given `def bar(**kwargs)`, check if the function `bar` only accepts keyword arguments of type `JSON`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly kwargs or args, so essentially yes that’s what i’m trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way of currently doing this, if `fn` has an arbitrary signature. I believe that the next best thing is generating errors at the call site (see
[Pyright playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAYwgG2QUwTYEB2BnAOgEMAjBOIvRADwFgAoUSWOGATzGBwHMKqYGDdmDRwAUgGUA8gDk4AXhoEAskTCceAbTwwoAGnHSZAXTgAfJRLQBHAK5ocCNJsmzTFnVHNwu8CwDNkCCI-OBIIFG8ZXDRBegRkSioAfVcZKRxkNgBhIlRSdAAKGAIABSgIGAgkZABKAC4GOGa4ABM0fzhk5IQ85G7CvDRkfwMAegMAKiIobjx6w1kpyYBrAHcZuYW02rgAWgA%2BRZkFgjO49s6QNBAIYAAvZwAxBYRqAlz8knRNM4IDEoAQRwbGMxkK-hwCye412hzgT28qSMGSyn0S3zQjXoLTgUDQMFsUBwcEhcQAAtdbg9YvRLqTCkQFr4DCQFp4DAh2QTNL5jHCjp5Tud6HEGP5CgBGAwAIhlBgA3tK4AAmAC%2BtQYQA)):

```py
import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t

type JSON = cx.Mapping[str, JSON] | cx.Sequence[JSON] | str | int | float | bool | None

class _JSONOnlyCallable(t.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, /, *args: JSON, **kwargs: JSON) -> JSON: ...

def memoize[F: cx.Callable[..., t.Any]](fn: F, /) -> F | _JSONOnlyCallable:
    return fn

@memoize
def f(a: int, b: str, c: set[int]) -> str: ...
```

```
>>> f(1, "", {1, 2})
             ^^^^^^
pyright: Argument of type "set[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "args" of type "JSON" in function "__call__"
```

Comment: Wow, it's a really rare case when attempt to use union instead of intersection gives sensible results. Beautiful!

Comment: Clever solution. I think this is as close you get since it seems you can’t express this relationship by type-annotating Callable.

Comment: @STerliakov variations of this question come up alot - I remember https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78013162/typehint-function-args-tupleargs-with-constraint-on-the-args and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644359/how-to-type-hint-a-function-which-takes-a-callable-and-its-required-positional-a (the latter, before mypy supported PEP 646). Given the demand for this feature, it's probably worth it for the typing system to explore ways for decorators to check decorated callables.

Comment: All these questions would be resolved by introducing `Intersection` type (e.g. with [`basedmypy`](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) this would be `_F = t.TypeVar('_F', bound='cx.Callable[..., t.Any] & _JSONOnlyCallable'); def memoize(fn: _F, /) -> _F: return fn` - and `@memoize def f(...` emits error as expected. Same applies to `asFloatOnlyCallable` and `asPositionalOnlyCallable` from those questions.

Comment: This makes me think that other solutions for "decorators to check decorated callables" might be premature and become obsolete with Intersection type introduction (https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213)